# Independency of the frame of reference of the strain rate tensor

Tags: tensors, fluid-dynamics

I've got a problem regarding tensors.

Premise: we are considering a fluid particle with a velocity $\mathbf{u}$ and a position vector $\mathbf{x}$; $S_{ij}$ is the *strain rate tensor*, defined in this way:

$\displaystyle{S_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} +\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\right)}.$

OK, the problem is in this paragraph taken from *Fluid Mechanics. Fifth Edition*, P. K. Kundu, I. M. Cohen, D. R. Dowling, 2011, p. 78:

> Here we also note that $S_{ij}$ is zero for any rigid body motion composed of translation at a spatially uniform velocity $\mathbf{U}$ and rotation at a constant rate $\mathbf{\Omega}$ (see Exercise 3.17).<sup>[*]</sup> Thus, $S_{ij}$ is independent of the frame of reference in which it is observed, even if $\mathbf{U}$ depends on time and the frame of reference is rotating.

My question is: why is $S_{ij}$ independent of the frame of reference in which it is observed? Sure, it is zero in every frame in which the fluid particle translates with *constant* linear-velocity $\mathbf{U}$ and rotates with *constant* angular-velocity $\mathbf{\Omega}$, but this doesn't explain why it should be the case "even if $\mathbf{U}$ depends on time and the frame of reference is rotating."

[*] This is the Exercise 3.17:

> For the flow field $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{U} + \mathbf{\Omega} \times \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{\Omega}$ are constant linear- and angular-velocity
>   vectors, use Cartesian coordinates to a) show that $S_{ij}$ is zero, and b)
>   determine $R_{ij}$.

[$R_{ij}$ is the *rotation tensor*: $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} -\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}}$.]

Comment: Already asked: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70888/independency-of-the-frame-of-reference-of-the-strain-rate-tensor

Comment: If you are going to ask [a question on more than one forum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70888), at least link all the questions together, so that people can see what answers have been posted and don't duplicate effort.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.